# Different URL's / Same Server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

) 
One server - multiple URl's coming in to it. In the root there is an htaccess file that handles the traffic and sends it to subfolders ... badly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXXXX.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!XXXXX).*)$ /XXXX/$1 [NC,L]
```

How would I go about altering this so that all requests starting with "XXXXX.com" start looking in the folder "myserver.com/XXXXX" and the url in the browser stays "XXXXX.com"??

It currently only works for files in the root of that folder - as soon as you click a link to another file within that folder (or subfolders) the URL goes back to being the main server URL.

Any help greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXXXX.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!XXXXX/).*)$ /XXXXX/$1 [NC,L]
```

Because it missed a `/` (after XXXXX in test RewriteRule uri). That was ok for root, but not for others.

Comment: Thanks Croises - your knowledge is much appreciated :-)